# Using MD5 on login page

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, passwords, md5

```
<?php

include("connect.php");
session_start();
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Username and password sent from form in HTML
    $myusername = $_POST['username'];
    $mypassword = $_POST['password'];

    $sql    = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $row    = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $active = $row['active'];
    $count  = mysql_num_rows($result);

    // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
    if ($count == 1) {
        session_register("myusername");
        $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;

        header("location: welcome.php");
    } else {
        $error = "Your username or password is invalid";
    }
}

?>
```

This is my current login code. On my registration page, I have it so that when it injects into the database, it injects the passwords already encrypted in MD5. However, I cannot seem to convert:

```
$mypassword=$_POST['password'];
```

Into MD5 to confirm to see if the password exists in the database. With this code, the passwords must not be encrypted. What should I change to make it so that it checks with the database **encrypted**?

Comment: `$mypassword=md5($_POST['password']);` ?

Comment: I don't get it. You can insert the `md5($_POST['password'])` in database and compare it also to the hashed password when logging in.

Comment: Ever heard of something called SQL injection?

Comment: sql query  should be password='".md5($mypassword)."'

Comment: When saving a password verifier just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Better yet use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt`, `passlib.hash` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a substantial of time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score 5):

Simply wrap `$_POST['password']` into `md5()` like so:

```
$mypassword = md5 ($_POST['password']);
```

Needless to say, you have a number of other problems, like feeding the database an unescaped username, and hashing passwords without a salt, not to mention using `md5()` in the first place; use the built-in `crypt()`, pbkdf2, bcrypt or scrypt function for that, or any other [key derivation function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function), preferably one that uses an up to date hash method and a large count (number of iterations). PHP 5.5 also introduced a simplified pasword hashing API, which you can look into [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). For even more PHP hashing-related tips, see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php).

Overall, as a developer, you can not live without giving [this fascinating post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/speed-hashing.html) a thorough read. Skip to the tl;dr at the bottom if you can't be bothered (and are okay with killing kittens).

Comment: Yes, although I had already changed the -1 to a +1 of course :)

Comment: Been researching for 30 mins your answer was the only one that helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

PHP recommends you not use MD5 to hash passwords: http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash

To answer your question directly, however, you can md5 a string using md5(). Example:

```
$mypassword = md5($_POST['password']);
```

And you can compare it later using the same thing:

```
"SELECT... WHERE password = '".md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($someValue))."'"
```

Comment: why under `mysqli_real_escape_string` the hashed string? That should be made before the encryption.

Comment: Doesn't md5 contain safe characters already... So escaping the string would change the hash. Should escape username when comparing as OP did not

Comment: Should escape everything, honestly. Should escape them before selecting or inserting, regardless of the `md5()`.

Comment: @garrettmurray No, the PHP md5 function will be evaluated before the SQL statement, so there is zero need to escape it. The only thing that will do is make it less compatible with other runtimes.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand the question. If you are storing password md5 encrypted in db you just need to compare like this `$myPassword = md5($_POST['password'])`

Comment: This is what I thought would work. (Sorry, little new to PHP and MySQL) When I change it to this, it doesn't confirm with the passwords in the database that are encrypted.

When the code is `$mypassword=$_POST['password'];` though, it confirms with passwords that aren't encrypted.

Comment: @user2655462 I suggest echoing out the md5 and physically compare the values to see what you are getting

Comment: @user2655462 There may be two issues here. 1. You aren't encrypting using md5. 2. Password is worong. I suggest you to do what amaster507 said.

Comment: @amaster507 Thank you for the advice. When I echo out the MD5 from the login page and compare it to the MD5 in the database, it is different.

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally you can put it like this:

```
$myPassword = md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));
```

But since there are proven vulnerabilities in [MD5 hash](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/security/md5-password-scrambler-no-longer-safe/12317), you can use other hash algorithm in [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php). Ideally, you can use SHA-512 like this:

```
$myPassword = hash('sha512',mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));
```

Take note that `mysqli_real_escape_string` is also important in making such queries to prevent [sql injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) then you can simply compare the hashed password when logging in.

Comment: But isn't that subjective to choose which one is better? Personally I prefer SHA512 base on its performance and bit size; and not to mention the built-in hash function for that in php. FYI: pbkdf2 is an implementation of appropriate SHA512 or Blowfish. You can't just simply run pbkdf2 hash. You have to exert more effort on creating separate function (user defined) just to implement it to your codes. Why bother?

Comment: Well, alternatively you could use `crypt` which at least uses a number of iterations in addition to a salt. But you are the one inventing a new method of password hashing, not me. Furthermore, I don't see why you would need to escape a string before feeding it to a hash...

Comment: -1 SHA-512 is too fast and you don't use a salt. By the way, the known vulnerabilities in MD5 don't apply to password hashing. And SQL escaping a string before hashing is silly SHA-512 is not MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

First wrap your variable into md5 function like this

```
$myPassword = md5($_POST['password']);
```

**how are you using just $myusername it must me some associative array because you are accessing a table ex(you also have to select **all*** not just id from db):-*

```
$_SESSION['login_user'] = $row['username'];
```

then change this

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
```

to this:-

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone! Okay so I was really stupid... put a limit in the database for the encrypted password. Also, thanks for the recommendations on how to hash my passwords and stuff.